# THE_PROCESS_HAS_FORKED_AND_YOU_CANNOT_USE_THIS_COREFOUNDATION_FUNCTIONALITY

Tags: ios, multithreading, fork, nsthread, serversocket

I am developing a chat program in iOS. But I could not solve a problem related to threads. Firstly, I created a server socket handling multiple connections in a thread. My code is like that:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(aMethod:) toTarget:[self class] withObject:nil];
    }

    void doprocessing(int sock)
    {
       int n;

       char *buffer = malloc(256);

       bzero(buffer,256);

       n = read(sock,buffer,255);
       if (n < 0)
       {
          perror("ERROR reading from socket");
          exit(1);
       }

      printf("Here is the message: %s\n",buffer);

      n = write(sock,"I got your message",18);

      if (n < 0)
      {
         perror("ERROR writing to socket");
         exit(1);
      }
   }

   +(void)aMethod:(id)param{

    int x;
    for(x=0;x<50;++x)
    {
    int sockfd, newsockfd, portno, clilen;
    char buffer[256];
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
    int  n;

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0)
    {
        perror("ERROR opening socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    portno = 5001;
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,
             sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
    {
        perror("ERROR on binding");
        exit(1);
    }

    listen(sockfd,5);
    clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
    while (1)
    {
        newsockfd = accept(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
        if (newsockfd < 0)
        {
            perror("ERROR on accept");
            exit(1);
        }

        int pid = fork();
        if (pid < 0)
        {
            perror("ERROR on fork");
            exit(1);
        }
        if (pid == 0)
        {

            close(sockfd);
            doprocessing(newsockfd);
            exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
            close(newsockfd);
        }
        } 
    }
}
```

As you know, I can not reach the gui elements in that thread. For this reason, I called mainThread function, but still I can not reach gui elements. I got this result:

```
The process has forked and you cannot use this CoreFoundation functionality safely. You MUST exec().
Break on __THE_PROCESS_HAS_FORKED_AND_YOU_CANNOT_USE_THIS_COREFOUNDATION_FUNCTIONALITY___YOU_MUST_EXEC__() to debug.
The process has forked and you cannot use this CoreFoundation functionality safely. You MUST exec().
Break on __THE_PROCESS_HAS_FORKED_AND_YOU_CANNOT_USE_THIS_COREFOUNDATION_FUNCTIONALITY___YOU_MUST_EXEC__() to debug.
The process has forked and you cannot use this CoreFoundation functionality safely. You MUST exec().
Break on __THE_PROCESS_HAS_FORKED_AND_YOU_CANNOT_USE_THIS_COREFOUNDATION_FUNCTIONALITY___YOU_MUST_EXEC__() to debug.
The process has forked and you cannot use this CoreFoundation functionality safely. You MUST exec().
Break on __THE_PROCESS_HAS_FORKED_AND_YOU_CANNOT_USE_THIS_COREFOUNDATION_FUNCTIONALITY___YOU_MUST_EXEC__() to debug.
The process has forked and you cannot use this CoreFoundation functionality safely. You MUST exec().
Break on __THE_PROCESS_HAS_FORKED_AND_YOU_CANNOT_USE_THIS_COREFOUNDATION_FUNCTIONALITY___YOU_MUST_EXEC__() to debug.
The process has forked and you cannot use this CoreFoundation functionality safely. You MUST exec().
Break on __THE_PROCESS_HAS_FORKED_AND_YOU_CANNOT_USE_THIS_COREFOUNDATION_FUNCTIONALITY___YOU_MUST_EXEC__() to debug.
The process has forked and you cannot use this CoreFoundation functionality safely. You MUST exec().
Break on __THE_PROCESS_HAS_FORKED_AND_YOU_CANNOT_USE_THIS_COREFOUNDATION_FUNCTIONALITY___YOU_MUST_EXEC__() to debug.
The process has forked and you cannot use this CoreFoundation functionality safely. You MUST exec().
Break on __THE_PROCESS_HAS_FORKED_AND_YOU_CANNOT_USE_THIS_COREFOUNDATION_FUNCTIONALITY___YOU_MUST_EXEC__() to debug.
The process has forked and you cannot use this CoreFoundation functionality safely. You MUST exec().
Break on __THE_PROCESS_HAS_FORKED_AND_YOU_CANNOT_USE_THIS_COREFOUNDATION_FUNCTIONALITY___YOU_MUST_EXEC__() to debug.
The process has forked and you cannot use this CoreFoundation functionality safely. You MUST exec().
Break on __THE_PROCESS_HAS_FORKED_AND_YOU_CANNOT_USE_THIS_COREFOUNDATION_FUNCTIONALITY___YOU_MUST_EXEC__() to debug.
```

If I do not use fork, it works. But my question is that how can i reach the gui elements by using fork function?

Comment: Is there any reason why you are not using GCD?

Comment: You cannot fork() or exec() on iOS devices (compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619252/fork-on-iphone). Or is this for a jailbroken device?

Comment: I used GCD but in this case, the server connection sometimes fails. I tried many things but I could not find a better solution. Yes this is for a jailbroken device.

Answer (score 2):

(As you said in a comment, this is for jailbroken devices, otherwise you could not use fork() or exec() at all.)

You are running into a limitation of the Apple frameworks
which is documented in [Obsolete Programming Techniques](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2083/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003794-CH1-SUBSECTION64) in Technical Note TN2083 "Daemons and Agents":

> **Daemonizing Frameworks**
>
> Many Mac OS X frameworks do not work reliably if you call fork but do
>   not call exec. The only exception is the System framework and, even
>   there, the POSIX standard places severe constraints on what you can do
>   between a fork and an exec.